# Do you double up with +1/+1 counters on Fungal Behemoth?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If you have a [Fungal Behemoth](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Fungal%20Behemoth) with 2 +1/+1 counters on it and no other creature with any +1/+1 counters on it, is the fun guy a 4/4? The two counters give it a base power and toughness of 2/2 and then those very same counters give it another +2/+2. I'm pretty sure that is how it works, just needed confirmation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's correct, +1/+1 counters placed on Fungal Behemoth are essentially doubled up in effectiveness.

- Each +1/+1 counter on Fungal Behemoth gives it +1/+1, as normal.
- Fungal Behemoth additionally has an ability that counts the number of +1/+1 counters on your creatures, and gives it +1/+1 for each of those.

These both happen cumulatively, and the ability considers even counters placed on the fun guy itself. So each +1/+1 counter placed on the Fungal Behemoth gives it +2/+2 — once from the counter itself, once from its ability.

This is also described in a ruling on Fungal Behemoth:

> Any +1/+1 counters on Fungal Behemoth itself count toward its base power and toughness, then give it a power and toughness bonus. For example, if there are two +1/+1 counters on Fungal Behemoth and three on other creatures you control, Fungal Behemoth is a 7/7 creature.

Comment: but only the counters from creatures. The one from llanowar reborn does not count, right?

Comment: Right, Llanowar Reborn is not a creature.

Comment: @doppelgreener Unless it is a creature, because an effect (like the abilities of a certain elven Planeswalker or some cards from various Zendikar blocks) has turned it into one.